# Storing a data from selected value in PHP

Tags: php

I want to store a data from a variable to be use on different condition.

Here's my view

```html-php
<form class="col-12" name="submission" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>submission">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 input-group">
        <select class="custom-select" id="section" name="section">
            <option selected>Section</option>
            <?php foreach ($get_section->result() as $row) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row->section; ?>"><?php echo strtoupper($row->section); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<form>
```

So I wanted to store the value that I selected in an PHP varible

I tried this method but im getting

```php
$var = $_POST['section'];
```

But im getting this error message

```php
Undefined array key "section"
```

Comment: Remove <a> from  <option value="<?php echo  $row->section; ?>"><?php echo  strtoupper($row->section); ?></option><a>

Comment: oh yes thanks! but it doesnt change anything

Comment: Is this in a form?

Comment: yes, i just put the form tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: no sorry, i did it. I wanna hold the value i get on selected item and keep it. And gonna use it for another condition

Comment: 'Undefined array key' "section" that is just the output of "$row->section;" and passed as plain string to the other php....did you check the output of $row->section